# Ubuntu Best Practice to give program(Atom) access to my SSH private key and not run program as sudo

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, atom-editor

I'm am using Atom to connect to a server via SSH. From what I understand the private key should be only readable via root.

I am not able to run Atom as root, and from what I understand it's dangerous to run as root b/c of compiling malicious code.

Comment: Your private key should only be readable by *you*. You shouldn't need to run anything as `root` for what you're describing here.

Comment: The program I needs access to my SSH key so I can use it for file management on another server. Wouldn't this necessitate root or different privs on my key?